# Check permission on every page

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my web site i need to check permission on every page,
i found my self repeating the same code every page.

this is one of my pages

```
public partial class KitView : AmsBasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IddUser user = new IddUser();
        user = (IddUser)Session["user"];

        bool isAdmin = user.roles.Where(IddRole => IddRole.R_ID.Equals(3)).First().IsInRole;
        bool isIddTeam = user.roles.Where(IddRole => IddRole.R_ID.Equals(2)).First().IsInRole;
        bool isProductionTeam = user.roles.Where(IddRole => IddRole.R_ID.Equals(1)).First().IsInRole;

        if (isAdmin)
        {
            hypAddComponent.Visible = true;
            hypAddComponent.NavigateUrl = "AddComponent.aspx?CKID=" + Request.QueryString["CKID"];
        }



    }
}
```

how is the best practice to have the roles: isAdmin,isIddTeam,isProductionTeam
in every page but not repeating the code below in every page code

```
IddUser user = new IddUser();
        user = (IddUser)Session["user"];

        bool isAdmin = user.roles.Where(IddRole => IddRole.R_ID.Equals(3)).First().IsInRole;
        bool isIddTeam = user.roles.Where(IddRole => IddRole.R_ID.Equals(2)).First().IsInRole;
        bool isProductionTeam = user.roles.Where(IddRole => IddRole.R_ID.Equals(1)).First().IsInRole;
```

Comment: are you using asp.net mvc or plain asp.net?

Comment: Your question needs a better title.

Comment: You should look up on [asp.net authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd(v=vs.100).aspx). You will be able to declaratively set your configurations in web.config.

Comment: i want to keep with my authorization, i'm using webforms,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added in my AmsBasePage class that all pages inherit from .
this code

```
private bool _isAdmin;
    private bool _isIddTeam;
    private bool _isProductionTeam;




    protected bool isAdmin
    {
        get { return _isAdmin; }
        set { _isAdmin = value; }
    }

    protected bool isIddTeam
    {
        get { return _isIddTeam; }
        set { _isIddTeam = value; }
    }

    protected bool isProductionTeam
    {
        get { return _isProductionTeam; }
        set { _isProductionTeam = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should put your authorization code in your Master Page (ASP.NET Web Form) or Layout Page (ASP.NET MVC). That way, your authorization logic will only be placed in one location and runs on every page.

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to avoid redundant codes, i would suggest to write your `authorization` logic in a sepearte `class` or you can even write the `aurthorization` logic in a `MasterPage` if you have any. Then inherit them in your `webforms`.
>   Note: in your `webforms` you will have to `override` your `page_load` event so that the `authorization` from your inherited base class runs first.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to avoid repeating authorization code, you should do it at a central location.

there can be many ways for that, but I can suggest you few

- Use Master Page - and write the authorization code in Master Page's OnLoad
- Create a HttpModule - Insert your own Module in the ASP.NET Page Events PipeLine and handle all the authorization and authentication logic

Now this is what I did in a multi-million $ Project

- Create a PageBase.cs being inherited from `System.Web.UI.Page` - which you are already doing
- Create a constructor of the PageBase, in which you can pass current Page permissions i.e.

  ```
   public void PageBase(AppActivityEnum PageView, AppActivityEnum PageEdit, AppActivityEnum PageDelete)
  {
    this.pageView = PageView;
    this.pageEdit=PageEdit;
    this.PageDelete=PageDelete;

    VerifyPermission();
  }
  ```

where VerifyPermission() is:

```
     public void VerifyPermission()
    {
        var currentUser= SessionHelper.GetCurrentUser();
        var permissions = Utility.GetUserPermissions(currentUser.RoleId);

            this.CanView=permissions.Contains((int)this.pageView);

            this.CanEdit=permissions.Contains((int)this.pageEdit);

            this.CanDelete=permissions.Contains((int)this.pageDelete);

    }
```

now these three variables i.e. `CanView, CanEdit, CanDelete` are public properties in `PageBase`, hence available to all your pages(wherever you have inherited).
and you can set your controls(add button, delete button), page visibility based on these variables.

so basically, you create an Activity Table for storing ref of each of the Pages. where Activity table looks like

- Id
- Name
- Value
- Parent

a typical entry in this table is like:

```
  1 Module-Master           MMaster       NULL 
  2 Module-Master-View      MMasterView    1 
  3 Module-Master-Edit      MMasterEdit    1 
  4 Module-Master-Delete    MMasterDelete  1
```

and you maintain RoleAppActivtyMapping (obviously):

```
 Id   RoleId  AppActivityId
   1    1        2
   1    1        3
   1    1        4
```

so RoleId one has all the three permissions.

so `GetUserPermissions(RoleId)` basically gets all the `RoleAppActivityMapping` entries corresponding to passed Role.

so on every page you call the PageBase' constructor to verify the view permissions. You pass the current Page's AppActivity Id in the constructor. 
and if CanView is false: you redirect to "UnAuthorized" page upon hitting the url.

Answer (score 0):

check your authorization in the master page. That way, I will be checked once and repeatation can be avoided.